# Move Bottomsheet Along With Keyboard Which Has Textfield in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to make a bottomsheet that has a text field. But, bottomsheet is overlapped by the keyboard. Is there a way to move bottomsheet above the keyboard?

I have this:

[image]

I need this:

[image]

How i can make it in Jetpack Compose ?

Comment: It works correct, if you want to see a whole bottom sheet, add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** to your activity in manifest

Comment: I have windowSoftInputMode in manifest.

Comment: better to provide current value, it can help

Comment: I fix this problem, there was a problem due to full window style

Comment: @RuTiKeyOne 
Welcome to SO. Please, consider adding your solution and marking it as accepted after a couple of days. It's encouraged:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/
So others that may have the same problem find your solution :)

Comment: Couldn't you type your answer? @RuTiKeyOne

Answer (score 1):

If you use the full window style in your activity, then add `windowInsets` parameter in your `ModalBottomSheet` composable and set the value to `WindowInsets.ime`. This will make the soft keyboard can be detected and adjust its layout accordingly when the keyboard is displayed.

```
@Composable
fun ReviewBottomSheet(
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    modalBottomSheetState: SheetState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .then(modifier),
        windowInsets = WindowInsets.ime
    ) {
        TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, label = "Text")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered here for similar issue:https://stackoverflow.com/a/77504046/12995187

Seems like issue is solved in 1.2.0-alpha12 version. You can try:

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha12")
```

Comment: The problem still occurs for me after updating dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you have set skipPartiallyExpanded to true in sheetState then turn it to false or not use it and add  windowInsets = WindowInsets.ime in ModalBottomSheet.

use this : -
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = false)

Its causing problem of extra padding in between keyboard and ModalBottomSheet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).